# Manage Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 from same machine

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to manage Windows Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 from within itself? E.g. not remotely.

I'd like to be able to manage VMs as well as connect to and work with a a VM in full screen mode.

This would provide the ability to, for instance, install Hyper-V on a laptop and then connect to the VM and work per usual - switching between running VMs in the process.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to start machines, stop machines, change disks, etc. you can do that with the [PowerShell Management Library for Hyper V](https://pshyperv.codeplex.com/). This will just allow you to manage it via CLI. If you actually want to attach to the VM console, this is impossible on Hyper V Server. In order to do that, you'd need to install Windows Server and enable the Hyper V role.

Answer (score 1):

No, Hyper-V server is not meant to be controlled locally.

Or - yes. Best bet would be installing PowerShell / PowerShell cmdlets to manage it (there are some on codeplex). No fancy UI though.

You are better off installing Server 2008 R2 on the laptop with Hyper-V.